# PhantomJS memory leak and process exit failure

Tags: memory-leaks, phantomjs

I am currently working on a project with PhantomJS that evaluates a list of web pages specified by a CSV file.  I installed NPM and node.js to use in my program.

Here is the program:

```
var async = require("async");
var webpage = require('webpage'),
    fs = require('fs');

var file_h = fs.open('C:\\Users\\morgan\\Documents\\FantasyApp\\URLPlayerListActive.txt', 'r');
var urls = [];
while (!file_h.atEnd()) {
    urls.push(file_h.readLine());
}

async.eachSeries(urls, function (url, done) {
    console.log(url)
    var page = webpage.create();
    page.open("http://"+url, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to access network');
            console.log(status)
            var closeresults = page.close();
        } else {
            var evalresults = page.evaluate(function() {
                try {
                    table2csv('pgl_basic');
                    try {
                        ga('send','event','Tool','Action','CSV');
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                    var list = document.querySelectorAll('#csv_pgl_basic');
                    var stats = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        stats.push(list[i].innerText);
                    }
                    return stats;
                    var closeresults = page.close();
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
            try {
                fs.write("C:\\Users\\morgan\\Documents\\FantasyApp\\Data\\"+url+".txt",     evalresults.join('\n'), 'w');
                var closeresults = page.close();
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
                var closeresults = page.close();
            }
        }
        done();
    });
});
phantom.exit();
```

My symptoms are either the process memory increases until it reaches my Windows maximum and crashes, OR it finishes my list and the process hangs around forever.

I can implement a work around for either of these problems, but because they both happen, I am unable to put this script to work.

I am looking for assistance preventing the memory leak or simply closing my process when the script is finished.  It is possible that these symptoms are from the same root cause.

Answer (score 1):

If the page is not correctly garbage collected, you can try to use the same instance over and over again. The other thing is that you should call `phantom.exit` when the script actually finished e.g. in the callback of `eachSeries`.

```
var page = webpage.create();
async.eachSeries(urls, function (url, done) {
    console.log(url)
    page.open("http://"+url, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to access network');
            console.log(status)
        } else {
            var evalresults = page.evaluate(function() {
                try {
                    table2csv('pgl_basic');
                    try {
                        ga('send','event','Tool','Action','CSV');
                    }
                    catch (e) {}
                    var list = document.querySelectorAll('#csv_pgl_basic');
                    var stats = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                        stats.push(list[i].innerText);
                    }
                    return stats;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            });
            try {
                fs.write("C:\\Users\\morgan\\Documents\\FantasyApp\\Data\\"+url+".txt",     evalresults.join('\n'), 'w');
            } catch(e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        done();
    });
}, function(err){
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Some other issues:

- `page.close` doesn't return anything, so `closeresults` will be `undefined`.
- Any statement that comes after `return` cannot be executed.
- `page` is not defined in the page context (inside `page.evaluate`) and therefore `page.close();` produces an error which may break your code.

Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html) events to see if there are errors.